# How to convert strings in array to unsigned integers?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
char switch_list[] = {
    "PINB >> 7", 
    "PIND >> 1", 
    "PINB >> 1", 
    "PIND >> 0}"
};

void values(void){
    uint8_t switch_value = 0;
        if (i == 0){
            switch_value = (PINB >> 7) & 1; 
        }
        if (i == 1){
            switch_value = (PIND >> 1) & 1;
        }
        if (i == 2){
            switch_value = (PINB >> 1) & 1;
        }
        if (i == 3){
            switch_value = (PIND >> 0) & 1;
        }
        SOME OTHER OPERATIONS GO HERE
}
```

I need to interpret the **switch_list** values as unsigned integers somehow, but I am not able to  make any changes to the array (it needs to remain a char array). **PINB** and the others have defined 8 bit value in the libraries. I would like to create a for loop that looks something like this:

```
uint8_t switch_value = 0;
    for (int i = 0, i < sizeof(switch_list)/sizeof(switch_list[0]); i++){
            switch_value = **********[i] & 1; 
         SOME OTHER OPERATIONS GO HERE
        }
}
```

Where ********* is the same as **switch_list** but instead of being of char type, it is **uint8_t**. Can anyone provide any tips?

Comment: you want to read the char array, extract the specific variable name (`PINB` or `PIND`) and then perform a shift on it and return as a `uint8`?

Comment: Extract the value, return it as a uint_8 then perform as shift on it. Or just literally insert the text of the array index into that for loop

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but it seems to me you are trying to get a text string executed as code (!?). That's not possible.

Comment: How are those `PINx` defined?

Comment: You could make an array of function pointers, e.g. `uint8_t f0() {return PINB >> 7;}` or just make a support function if you don't like all the if statements inside the loop.

Comment: How many `PINx` values are possible?

Comment: You can pack the information in a `struct` with bit fields.

Comment: @4386427 it is possible. He just needs to write the interpreter.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 yaaa, that would be a real fun way to make simple stuff complicated

Comment: Good programming exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your knowledge about the array and create a function to convert your values from `"PINB >> 7"` to `PINB >> 7`. The assumptions I made are:

1. The string always starts with "PIN" and then has a "B" or a "D" (can be easily modified )
2. The string will then do an operation (currently I only support ">>" but this can too be easily modified)
3. Last char in the string is a 1-char number (again, can be modified according to your knowledge about the string)

Using that, I can create a `convert` function

```
unsigned int convert(char * p);

/* PINB and the others have defined 8 bit value in the libraries
   so I'm making up their values here for convenience */
unsigned int PINB = 1024;
unsigned int PIND = 2048;

int main(){
    // deleted your ending }
    // and changed the type of the array
    char* switch_list[] = {
        "PINB >> 7", 
        "PIND >> 1", 
        "PINB >> 1", 
        "PIND >> 0"
    };

    unsigned int switch_value;
    // , should be ;
    // don't compare signed with unsigned
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(switch_list)/sizeof(switch_list[0]); i++){
        switch_value = convert(switch_list[i]); 
        printf("%u\n", switch_value);
    }

    return 0;
}

// assuming string must be exactly long as "PINB >> 7"
unsigned int convert(char * p){
    if(!p || strlen(p) != strlen("PINB >> 7")){
        printf("error\n");
        return (unsigned)-1;
    }

    unsigned int n;
    // use a string compare or, in your case, since only the 4th char is different:
    if(p[3] == 'B')
        n = PINB;
    if(p[3] == 'D')
        n = PIND;
    // note I'm not handling a case where the 4th letter isn't {'B', 'D'}, according to my assumption (the 1st).

    // use your knowledge about the string inside switch_list
    return n >> (p[strlen(p) - 1] - '0');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `PINx` thingies would evaluate to a type `PIN_T` you can do:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for size_t */
#include <inttypes.h> /* for uint8_t */

/* other include here */


struct switch_s
{
  PIN_T * ppin;
  uint8_t offset;
};

struct switch_s switches[] =
{
  {&PINB, 7},
  {&PIND, 1},
  {&PINB, 1},
  {&PIND, 0},
  /* more here */
};

int main(void)
{ 
  for (size_t i; i < sizeof switches / sizeof *switches; ++i)
  {
    uint8_t switch_value = (*switches[i].ppin >> switches[i].offset) & 1;

    /* Work with switch_value here ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO, this is by far the best approach. I'm not sure that `&PINx` is correct but that's not important. The principle is what's important.